# Does the canonical bijection between $\mathcal P(S)$ and $2^S$ use the axiom of choice or the law of excluded middle

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

Let $\mathcal{P}(S)= \{X \ | X \subseteq S\}$ and $2^S = \{g \ | \ g: S \rightarrow \{0,1\}\}$ and consider the bijection

$$f : \mathcal{P}(S) \rightarrow 2^S$$

Defined for all $X \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ and all $s \in S$ by
$$
f(X)(s) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 \ \  \Leftrightarrow \ \  s \in X\\
            0 \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \  s \notin X\\
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

In other words, every subset of $S$ is mapped by $f$ to its characteristic function, and every function $g$ on $S$ is mapped by $f^{-1}$  to the set $\{ s: g(s)=1 \} $.

Does this bijection use the axiom of choice or unbounded law of the excluded middle?

Comment: Why do you think choice was used here? I mean, other than "LEM follows from choice" kind of way.

Comment: Believe it or not, choice and lem are used so much in many of my courses but really breaking them down and getting an intuition about them is not something we commonly do.  So unfortunately I am left to math stack exchange to help develop this ability, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bijection definitely uses the law of excluded middle, but absolutely no axiom of choice.

As Asaf points out in the comments, why would it use the axiom of choice ? Have you "made a choice" at any point  ?

As for the law of excluded middle, it is used in defining the characteristic function of a subset : if $X\subset S$, your function $f(X)$ is defined on $\{x\in S \mid x\in X\lor x\notin X\}$, and without the law of excluded middle, this may happen not to be $S$. What happens is that in some "intuitionistic universes", $2$ is replaced by a set $\Omega$ of "truth values", and so $f(X)(s)$ is "the truth value of "$x\in X$".

Of course, classically, there are only two truth values (true or false), hence the $2$, but without the law of excluded middle there can be more, and so you get a larger $\Omega$; and you have a bijection $\mathcal{P}(X)\simeq \Omega^X$.

Comment: In particular, choosing $S$ as some singleton set, call it $1$, then $\mathcal P(1)$ basically is $\Omega$ (sometimes by definition) and the bijection becomes $\Omega\cong\mathbf 2$ which comes close to being a direct statement of the law of the excluded middle.

Comment: any idea about where i could read about this sort of thing?